# Update or Remove Item from Cart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I manage the orders made by the customers. My `Order` table is connected to the model `Cart`. The model `Cart` is connected to the `Product` model `Many to Many` which gave the association table `line_items` which includes `id_cart`, `id_product`, and `quantity`. But for the `Cart`, I want to add the option to `update` and `delete` an element of the `Cart`. I met a blocking - more precisely in the view `Order` where at the end I show the list of the elements in the `Cart` as follows

```
<h3> Order Details </ h3>
<table class = "table-bordered table">
  <td> Designation </ td> <td> Quantity </ td> <td> Price </ td> </ tr>
  <% order.cart.line_items.each do | item | %>
    <tr align = "center">
      <td> <% = f.text_field: product_id,: value => item.product.title,: readonly => true, class: 'form-control'%> </ td>
      <td> <% = f.text_field: qte,: value => item.qte, class: 'form-control'%> </ td>
      <td> <% = number_to_currency (product.inc.unit, unit: "F", separator: ",", format: "% n% u")%> </ td>
    </ Tr>
  <% end%>
</ Table>
```

There I will have the fields textfield with default value what the customer had ordered allowing the modification. But the problem is that the attibutes `product_id` and `qte` do not belong to the model `order` but earlier to the model `line_items`, so I will not have permission to insert:

```
unpermitted parameters: :product_id, :qte
```

I even try the method `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and I will have permission. But the transaction will not commit but rollback.

And thank you for helping me for this bug that prevents me from advancing for days

the submitted params look like this

```
    <%= form_with(model: order,:remote => true)  do |f| %>
<div class="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
      <div class="header">
          <h4 class="title"> Edite Order</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <!--  Order Reference-->
              <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label><%= f.label :ref,"Reference Order "%></label>
                      <%= f.text_field :ref, :value => "ABC-123-NY#{@order.id}",:readonly => true,class: ' form-control' %>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Supplier List -->
              <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label><%= f.label :supplier_id,"Fournisseur"%></label>
                      <%=f.collection_select :supplier_id,Fournisseur.all,
                    :id,:namefrs,{required: true},id:"listfrs",class: 'form-control'%>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- boutton update -->
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <%= f.submit 'Modifier',:name => "valid",:class => 'btn btn-info btn-fill pull right'%>
                  </div>
              </div>


             </div>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="card">
      <div class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- Date Order -->
              <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label><%= f.label :date_order,"Date"%></label>
                      <%= f.date_select :date_order, label: false, placeholder: "Sélectionnez la date et l'heure",class: 'form-control'%>
                  </div>
              </div>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

      <div class="col" id="cart">
              <h3>Order</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr align="center" class="h4">
    <td>Designation</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    </tr>

    <% order.cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
    <tr align="center">

        <td><%= f.text_field :product_id,:value => item.product.title,:readonly => true,class: 'form-control'%></td>
        <td><%= f.text_field :qty, :value=>item.qty ,class: 'form-control' %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_currency(item.product.price, unit: "F",separator:",",format:"%n %u")%></td>
    </tr>


<% end %>
   </table>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

i have this in my controller Order

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      @order.cart.line_items.each do |item|
        item.qty = params[:qty]
      end
      format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are the attributes on `LineItem` really `id_cart` and `id_product`? By convention, then should be `cart_id` and `product_id`. (What does your `LineItem` model look like?) Where is the `f` coming from in `f.text_field`? Why do you have `</ Tr>` and `</ Table>` instead of `</ tr>` and `</ table>`? When trying to update your `line_item`, what do the submitted `params` look like? What are the whitelisted params in your controller?

Comment: yes jvillian I used scaffold to generate the attributes of LineItem and I have cart_id, product_id and qte and for the f (<% = form_with (model: order,: remote => true) do | f |% >) and to specify am in the view of the model order and the <tr> and <table> I am just mistaken in copying sticky but it is in minuscule and my model LineItem looks like this class LineItem <ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to: cart
   belongs_to: product
   total def
   product.price * qte
   end

end

Comment: What do the submitted params look like? What are the whitelisted params in your controller? (Please edit your question and don't put code in the comments.)